# redirect from HTTP to HTTPS behind AWS ELB

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, amazon-web-services, apache2

iv'e been looking through and am trying to find a solution to force HTTPS on apache-reverse-proxy behind AWS ELB without success.

my sites-enabled config file looks like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAlias *.domain.net
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} http
        RewriteRule https:// %{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
        ProxyPass / http://{10.10.10.21}/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://{10.10.10.21}/
</VirtualHost>
```

however i never get any redirect back to the browser when i hit the server on port 80. the proxypass and reverse are kicking in, but not the redirect.

i see that by enabling rewrite-trace level 8 as follows:

ive been on this for too long now....

any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what did you end up using on this?